# Introduce Reject Answer option along with accepted

Tags: feature-request, answers

I think it will help the searchers to identify which answer is correct and which one is wrong..! In stack overflow most of the answers are having 0 reputation, 60% question's answers are not accepted also.

I accept the down votes let me ask one more question. the down votes will indicate the answer is rejected then what is the need for [image]

Comment: Just downvote and comment. There is no point in marking answers as 'rejected'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just downvote answers that you feel are not helpful or correct, and leave a comment describing *why* the answer is wrong.

Hopefully, this will encourage the answerer to either correct the answer, or delete it.

Note that answers with a score of -3 or lower are also greyed out; you can interpret that as 'rejected' if you really want to.

Comment: Am talking about non-members who ware come into the site by google reference.

Comment: @SujithKarivelil: and they will *still see the negative score*, as well as the comments.

Comment: then what is the need for accepted 'tick mark'? up vote is their na?

Comment: To award the answerer when the question asker feels that one specific answer helped them the most.

Comment: same can done through up vote

Comment: @SujithKarivelil: the accepted question points are exempt from the reputation cap, and the marker is in **addition** to upvoting. Also, you cannot vote up until you have 15 points at least, so for *new* users they have no other options.

Comment: okey leave it was only a suggestion from my side

Comment: @SujithKarivelil: yes, and people are voting on the suggestion; you tagged it as a feature-request, and I gave my opinion on the request (i.e. I don't think there is a need for it).

Answer (score 4):

I want to point out one other thing concerning this.

When it comes to accepting an answer, obviously the OP is happy - they got their solution. It's pretty hard to abuse an acceptance checkmark because you're indicating to the world "this answer solved my problem."

On the flip-side, a mark that explicitly says "this did not solve my problem" is highly prone to abuse. There are a lot of people out there whom are very stubborn, and refuse to accept answers which tell them something they simply don't want to hear, even though they are 100% correct and *should* be the accepted answer. Letting them put a mark on it that basically tells the world "this is stupid" is very damaging, and only allowing the OP to downvote it limits that damage greatly. It's easy for other users to upvote it if it was actually useful, but there's nothing other users can do to get that ugly mark off of it.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this as I wanted this for a different reason.

That you can see in the list of unanswered questions, which question has so far only rejected answers opposed to which questions have "no accepted answer".

Unfortunatley often the OP does not bother to select an answer as correct and so often the state of "having answers" is synonomous to "has a good enoug answer"

Giving the OP the option to actively reject answers, could improve this, and make it easier to find real still unanswered questions with an active OP seeking for one. Also helping the OP to get more visibility for his request.

Maybe there is some low key solution to this.

Abuse of this can still be handled the usual way. Maybe make rejecting cost you some points or a Moderator can step in to close the issue if the OP is misusing this.